# Miracast connection error after joining ad domain

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, group-policy, windows-firewall, miracast

I have a situation where a laptop always ends up have a connection error when trying to establish a screen share using Miracast. Shockingly this phenomenon began right after joining the lenovo laptop to active directory domain. I have attempted to solve the problem by first uninstalling and reinstalling the dual wireless driver.

Secondly Modified Wireless Network Policy Permissions in order resolve the problem by way of going to the Network Permissions tab within the wireless network policy and then in the policy setting **Don't allow WiFi Direct groups** and **unchecking** this setting.

Also specifically for WIDI Config Firewall Exception Rules. I went into Windows Firewall Area via Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall >  Allow program or feature through firewall . Selected Wireless display and Allowed for Domain, Private and Public. Then click allow another app. Browse and navigated to  **C:\Windows\System32\WUDFHost.exe** and added this rule.

I also checked the policies Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings >Security Settings > Wireless Network (IEEE 802.11) Policies

Double clicked the setting for wireless policies and a dialog box appeared.
Opened the Network Permissions tab and selected **Allow everyone to create all user profiles.**

Finally opened regedit on laptop and then checked if the following registry entry Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Wireless
with the intention to delete the the XP folder if it existed there but there was no folder like that.

At the end of the day all of the above didn't do the trick. What am i missing here. Any suggestions. Workarounds ?

Comment: It may depend on policies at the domain level as those take precedence over local policies.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia can you shed some more light on that. Since i am already aware that some policies taking precedence but which one is taking precedence. ? I already detailed the policy settings in my above  question.

Comment: I meant that if there are policies at the domain level (AD) preventing it, then it doesn't matter what you do locally because those polices will be overridden .

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia All settings stated above were referring to none other but domain level policies. If all of the above have been double checked for precedence and nothing was found what could be causing this ?

Comment: *what could be causing this ?* If as you say it's at the domain level then sorry, I have no idea. It wasn't my understanding though because you started by saying the problem happened when the machine joined the domain and then mentioned things like WiFi and firewall settings, and registry which I understood as being done in the computer itself.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia No problem i thought you were aware of which policies i should be checking at the domain level. Would have preferred that instead of enduring on a wild goose chase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works after uninstalling VPN software from affected client. Most third party VPN solutions identify WiFi Direct (the underlying technology for Miracast) as a "Split Tunnel" and deem it a risk to security so they disable the functionality.